# Cannot connect to sandbox using JWT

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth2, connected-apps, jwt

I connected to Production Org with JWT through connected app without any difficulty.
However, by applying the same procedure, I could not connect to Sandbox using JWT.

Here is my command:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid consumerKeyOfConnectedAppInSandbox --jwtkeyfile myKey --username myUsername --setalias aliasName --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
```

And the error message goes:

> ERROR running force:auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token
> error, which is likely not an issue  with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the
> error: user hasn't approved this consumer

I have granted my profile "System Admin" to the connected app. I even created a permission set with my username inside. But the same error message still appears.

Comment: Did you add that jwtfile file in connected app? or the path for jwt file is correct?

Comment: Yes, the file is added. I got everything right in Production but in Sandbox it fails.

Comment: Adding : sfdx force:auth:logout --targetusername %USERNAME% -p
to the beginning of my build script fixed this!
ref-https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XrgnQAC

Comment: Neither is it the issue. I had logged out of my sandbox before I ran this command.

Comment: Did you create a new connected app in your sandbox, or "install" the same app that you made/use in production? If you "installed" the connected app from production (so that the consumer key is the same), you'll need to go through something like the web-server flow before you can use the JWT flow.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you need to use jwt auth here instead of, say, `force:auth:web:login`?

Comment: @DerekF, I created a new connected App in sandbox, not installing it from production. The reason I need jwt for sandboxes is that I am building up CI/CD pipeline using GitLab and need to push codes from git repo to orgs. Following the diagram in [this Trailhead project](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/automate-cicd-with-gitlab/update-the-app), I think I also need to push codes to sandbox for UAT from git. Let me know if I am mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure that the setting in connected app Permitted Users is selected as Admin approved users are pre-authorized, not User can self authorized

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the "https://test.salesforce.com" login url by your full sandbox instance url like "https://mydomain--mysandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce.com"